# Is it faster to replicate your data in hdfs for all your nodes?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, replication

If I have 6 data nodes, is it faster to turn replication to 6 so all the data is replicated across all my nodes so the cluster can split up queries (say in hive) without having to move data around?  I believe that if you have a replication of 3 and you put a 300GB file into HDFS, it splits it just across 3 of the data nodes and then when the 6 nodes need to be used for a query it has to move data around to the other 3 nodes that the data doesn't exist on, causing slower responses.. is that accurate?

Comment: There are some parts missing in the equation: how fast is your network and  your disks, how often do you intend to read the data?

Comment: I believe it's fast, since it's in Azure and should be pretty connected.  The disks are 16x500 IOPS according to the VM stats.  The data would be used all day long for queries.

Comment: I wouldn't advise you to store data on the VM disks, since they are really slow. You should also use Blob store rather than HDFS on these. You can get all of these for free by simply using HDInsight.

Comment: perhaps the best solution is to keep some statistics (number and type of queries, response times etc) and choose then

Answer (score 0):

I understand your means, you are talking about the data-locality. Generally speaking, the data-locality can reduce the run time, because it can save the time that block transmission by network. But in fact, if you don't open the "HDFS Short-Circuit Local Reads"(default it is off, please visit [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html)), the MapTask will also read the block by the TCP protocol, it means by network, even if block and MapTask both on the same node.

Recently, I optimize hadoop and HDFS, we use SSD to instead the HDD disk, but we found the effect is not good and time is not shorter.Because the disk is not the bottleneck and network load is not heavy. According to the result, we conclude the cpu is very heavy. If you want you know the hadoop cluster situation clearly, I advise you to use ganglia to monitoring the cluster, it can help you to analysis your cluster bottleneck.please see [here](http://ganglia.info/).

At last, hadoop is a very large and complicated system, the disk performance, cpu performance, network bandwidth, parameters values and also, there are many factor to consider. If you want to save time, you have much work to do, not just the replication factor.